# Integrity constraint error again

Tags: sql, oracle, referential-integrity

I am creating four database tables by the following schemas but am getting an integrity constraint violation error. Here is my entire schema along with the queries to populate the tables:

```
create table Employee(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    gender      char(1),
    street      varchar(10),
    city        varchar(10),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial));

create table company(
    company_name    varchar(20),
    city    varchar(10),
    primary key(company_name));

create table Works(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    company_name    varchar(20),
    salary      numeric(8,2),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, company_name),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee,
    foreign key(company_name) references company);

create table Manages(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    ManagerLastname varchar(10),
    MFirstName  varchar(10),
    MMidInitial char(1),
    start_date  date,
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee);

insert into Employee
    values('Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', 'F', '108th', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Brandy', 'Dan', 'L', 'M', 'P street', 'Lincoln');
insert into Employee
    values('Chen', 'Peter', 'K', 'M', '124th', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Clemson', 'Ann', 'M', 'F', 'O', 'Lincoln');
insert into Employee
    values('Dale', 'Mary', 'K', 'F', '132nd', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'F', 'P street', 'Lincoln');
insert into Employee
    values('Harrison', 'Susan', 'M', 'F', 'Old Mill', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Jackson', 'Kim', 'A', 'F', '178th', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Jason', 'Pat', 'M', 'M', '8th', 'C. Bluffs');
insert into Employee
    values('Kumar', 'Paul', 'T', 'M', 'Dodge', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Orr', 'Susanne', 'S', 'F', 'Q', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Peterson', 'Mike', 'E', 'M', 'Blondo', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Powell', 'Tom', 'E', 'M', 'Broadway', 'C. Bluffs');
insert into Employee
    values('Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', 'F', '168th', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Rand', 'Pam', 'R', 'F', '13th', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Schreck', 'Ann', 'P', 'F', '214th', 'Elkhorn');
insert into Employee
    values('Simon', 'Eric', 'K', 'M', '77th', 'Lincoln');
insert into Employee
    values('Smith', 'John', 'A', 'M', '8th', 'C. Bluffs');
insert into Employee
    values('Thomson', 'Ron', 'F', 'M', 'Farnam', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Young', 'Don', 'R', 'M', 'Dodge', 'Omaha');
insert into Employee
    values('Wong', 'Carole', 'S', 'F', 'Broadway', 'C. Bluffs');

insert into company
    values('First Bank', 'Omaha');
insert into company
    values('FDR', 'Omaha');
insert into company
    values('Lincoln Star', 'Lincoln');
insert into company
    values('Mutual of Omaha', 'Omaha');
insert into company
    values('Union Pacific (UP)', 'Omaha');

insert into Works
    values('Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', 'Mutual of Omaha', 48000);
insert into Works
    values('Brandy', 'Dan', 'L', 'FDR', 42000);
insert into Works
    values('Chen', 'Peter', 'K', 'FDR', 53000);
insert into Works
    values('Clemson', 'Ann', 'M', 'First Bank', 39000);
insert into Works
    values('Dale', 'Mary', 'K', 'Mutual of Omaha', 58000);
insert into Works
    values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'Union Pacific', 48700);
insert into Works
    values('Harrison', 'Susan', 'M', 'Union Pacific', 54320);
insert into Works
    values('Jackson', 'Kim', 'A', 'FDR', 68000);
insert into Works
    values('Jason', 'Pat', 'M', 'FDR', 83000);
insert into Works
    values('Kumar', 'Paul', 'T', 'FDR', 44000);
insert into Works
    values('Orr', 'Susanne', 'S', 'Lincoln Star', 32000);
insert into Works
    values('Peterson', 'Mike', 'E', 'First Bank', 37000);
insert into Works
    values('Powell', 'Tom', 'E', 'First Bank', 54000);
insert into Works
    values('Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', 'First Bank', 85000);
insert into Works
    values('Rand', 'Pam', 'R', 'FDR', 37000);
insert into Works
    values('Schreck', 'Ann', 'P', 'First Bank', 36000);
insert into Works
    values('Simon', 'Eric', 'K', 'Mutual of Omaha', 45000);
insert into Works
    values('Smith', 'John', 'A', 'FDR', 55000);
insert into Works
    values('Thomson', 'Ron', 'F', 'First Bank', 39000);
insert into Works
    values('Young', 'Don', 'R', 'Mutual of Omaha', 27000);
insert into Works
    values('Wong', 'Carole', 'S', 'First Bank', 44000);

insert into Manages
    values('Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', 'Dale', 'Mary', 'K', "15-SEP-2002");
insert into Manages
    values('Brandy', 'Dan', 'L', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', "05-MAR-2004");
insert into Manages
    values('Chen', 'Peter', 'K', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', "12-JUNE-2002");
insert into Manages
    values('Clemson', 'Ann', 'M', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', "30-AUG-2001");
insert into Manages
    values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'Harrison', 'Susan', 'M', "25-JAN-2003");
insert into Manages
    values('Jackson', 'Kim', 'A', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', "09-MAY-2008");
insert into Manages
    values('Kumar', 'Paul', 'T', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', "09-MAY-2001");
insert into Manages
    values('Rand', 'Pam', 'R', 'Smith', 'John', 'A', "15-JAN-2004");
insert into Manages
    values('Peterson', 'Mike', 'E', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', "30-AUG-2006");
insert into Manages
    values('Schreck', 'Ann', 'P', 'Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', "28-FEB-1996");
insert into Manages
    values('Simon', 'Eric', 'K', 'Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', "22-FEB-2004");
insert into Manages
    values('Smith', 'John', 'A', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', "05-MAR-2003");
insert into Manages
    values('Thomson', 'Ron', 'F', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', "30-AUG-1998");
insert into Manages
    values('Wong', 'Carole', 'S', 'Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', "28-FEB-2001");
insert into Manages
    values('Young', 'Don', 'R', 'Dale', 'Mary', 'K', "15-SEP-2007");
```

And here is the error I'm getting again:

```
Schema Creation Failed: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER_4_3C8F2.SYS_C00778260) violated - parent key not found
```

It would be great to get another set of eyes to take a look at this and see what's going wrong with it... I'm wondering if I should have created/populated the tables in a different order but I thought that what I was doing was correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

----UPDATE---- Also I am using SQL Fiddle and Oracle 11g R2.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to insert a value to child table but that value is not exist in parent table. Try to re validate your data set again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Few errors noted...

```
insert into Works 
    values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'Union Pacific (UP)', 48700);
insert into Works
    values('Harrison', 'Susan', 'M', 'Union Pacific (UP)', 54320);
```

-- Changed 'Union Pacific' to 'Union Pacific (UP)'

```
insert into Manages
    values('Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', 'Dale', 'Mary', 'K', '15-SEP-2002');
insert into Manages
    values('Brandy', 'Dan', 'L', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', '05-MAR-2004');
insert into Manages
    values('Chen', 'Peter', 'K', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', '12-JUNE-2002');
insert into Manages
    values('Clemson', 'Ann', 'M', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', '30-AUG-2001');
insert into Manages
    values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'Harrison', 'Susan', 'M', '25-JAN-2003');
insert into Manages
    values('Jackson', 'Kim', 'A', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', '09-MAY-2008');
insert into Manages
    values('Kumar', 'Paul', 'T', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', '09-MAY-2001');
insert into Manages
    values('Rand', 'Pam', 'R', 'Smith', 'John', 'A', '15-JAN-2004');
insert into Manages
    values('Peterson', 'Mike', 'E', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', '30-AUG-2006');
insert into Manages
    values('Schreck', 'Ann', 'P', 'Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', '28-FEB-1996');
insert into Manages
    values('Simon', 'Eric', 'K', 'Anderson', 'Susan', 'L', '22-FEB-2004');
insert into Manages
    values('Smith', 'John', 'A', 'Jason', 'Pat', 'M', '05-MAR-2003');
insert into Manages
    values('Thomson', 'Ron', 'F', 'Powell', 'Tom', 'E', '30-AUG-1998');
insert into Manages
    values('Wong', 'Carole', 'S', 'Quinn', 'Jacky', 'M', '28-FEB-2001');
insert into Manages
    values('Young', 'Don', 'R', 'Dale', 'Mary', 'K', '15-SEP-2007');
```

-- Changed all double quotes to single quoted

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem:

```
insert into Works values('Gill', 'Mary', 'L', 'Union Pacific', 48700);
```

'Union Pacific' is not one of your companies, you have 'Union Pacific (UP)'

As an aside, this is a really shabby way to do it anyway. Duplicating your data across tables like this is going to mean you have problems like this over and over again.

You should really have a surrogate key for each of your reference data tables (`Employee` & `Company`) and your detail tables (`Works` and `Manages`) should use those. For example:

```
create table Employee(
    Id          numeric(8),
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    gender      char(1),
    street      varchar(10),
    city        varchar(10),
    primary key(Id));
```

---

```
create table company(
    Id           numeric(8),
    company_name varchar(20),
    city         varchar(10),
    primary key(Id));
```

---

```
create table Works(
    Employee_Id numeric(8),
    Company_Id  numeric(8),
    salary      numeric(8,2),
    primary key(Employee_Id, Company_Id),
    foreign key(Employee_Id) references Employee(Id),
    foreign key(Company_Id) references Company(Id);
```

---

```
create table Manages(
    Employee_Id,
    Manager_Id,
    start_date  date,
    primary key(Employee_Id,Manager_id),
    foreign key(Employee_Id) references Employee(Id),
    foreign key(Manager_Id) references Employee(Id));
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the better way to write it up...

I fixed the UP error but now I am getting this error when trying to build the schema:
Schema Creation Failed: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Any ideas on that one? Thanks again.

Comment: Refer my post... All your statements are cured @user1462294

Comment: with your original schema?

Comment: Double quotes should be single, as per @realspirituals

Comment: @David - good point well made, I was in a bit of a hurry and forgot to do that.. Have edited the post. HAven't added any unique constraints, though, will leave that up to the OP if he/she chooses to change his/her design..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee**(column)**
```

Your forgot the Employee column.